# How to insert json data with special characters like % or ' in MySQL from Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I was successful in **description1** but got error for **description2** (exist **%**) and **description3** (exist **'** )

How can I escape such special characters in JSON object value at insert/update?

**NB**: In mySQL table, `description` column's data type is: **JSON**

```
 let description1 =
           {
            text: {
                data: Click Here,
                size: 36,
                alignment: center
                 },
             others: something string
           };
let description2 =
           {
            text: {
                data: Click rate 30%,
                size: 36,
                alignment: center
                 },
             others: something string
           };
 let description3 =
           {
            text: {
                data: Click Here,
                size: 36,
                alignment: center
                 },
             others: something special alamin's string
           };
 let dbConf = {
                connectionLimit: parseInt(DB_POOL_MAX),
                host: DB_HOST,
                user: DB_USERNAME,
                password: DB_PASSWORD,
                database: DB_DATABASE,
                multipleStatements: true
            };
const dbConnection = makeDb(dbConf);
const dbConnectionObject = util.promisify(dbConnection.query).bind(dbConnection);
let sql = `INSERT INTO product_description (product_id, description) VALUES ('${pdid}','${JSON.stringify(description})')`;
let result = await dbConnectionObject(sql);
```

Comment: *How to insert json data with special characters like % or ' in MySQL* These symbols must be escaped in provided string literal value according to MySQL language rules. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html

Comment: Thank you a lot! If it would be a single string then I can use an escaped string literal but for complex JSON. Can you, please give me a sample query/example of how will i use it as like JSON object?

{
 "list": [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Sample Category",
   "description": "Lorem Ipsum 100% book."
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Sample Category",
   "description": "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
  }
 ],
 "sort": 3,
 "title": "Sample Title",
 "status": true,
 "details": "Sample Offer",
 "subtitle": "Sample Offer"
}

Comment: Please [read the documentation on how to perform queries and pass arguments](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries).

Answer (score 0):

In here problem is occurring because of character(**'**), so if you try to insert your `JSON.stringify` data after replacing character("**'**") with character("**\'**") then it will work. you can try as like following.

```
var data = JSON.stringify(description3);
data = data.split("'").join("\\'");
const dbConnection = makeDb(dbConf);
const dbConnectionObject =util.promisify(dbConnection.query).bind(dbConnection);
let sql = `INSERT INTO product_description (product_id, description) VALUES ('${pdid}','${data})')`;
let result = await dbConnectionObject(sql);
```

Comment: It's much better to suggest using [the built-in escape function](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) instead of trying to do it manually.